# How to call asynchronous wcf method in using statement?

Tags: c#, wcf, asynchronous, using-statement

In synchronous model it's simply

```
using (MyServiceClient msc = new MyServiceClient())
{
   msc.Method();
}
```

but if I must wait to end of this method, and then do something, it can't work

```
private void EventHandler<MethodCompletedEventArgs> myEventHandler = new EventHandler<MethodCompletedEventArgs>(methodBody);

using (MyServiceClient msc = new MyServiceClient())
{
   msc.MethdCompleted += myEventHandler;
   msc.BeginMethod();
}

private void MethodBody()
{
//exception: client state is aborted
}
```

Also how to call async mehod in `using` statement?

Comment: Which type of application is calling the service?

Comment: Call Dispose in your event handler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store a reference to your service client and manually invoke its `Dispose` method once the event calls back. You just have to do some extra work managing exceptions and generally ensuring that `Dispose` is called eventually. Also watch for conditions where you might create/overwrite multiple instances of `msc` while waiting for an old one to complete:

One way to make sure that you don't dispose the wrong instance if you execute the same code multiple times is to use a local lambda/anonymous function:

```
MyServiceClient msc = new MyServiceClient();

msc.MethdCompleted += (sender, args) => 
{
    try
    {
        myEventHandler(sender, args);
    }
    finally
    {
        msc.Dispose();
    }
};

msc.BeginMethod();
```

It might get a bit messier than that; if an exception is thrown on `msc.BeginMethod()` you should catch that as well and call `Dispose` most likely (but you don't want to call `Dispose` more than once)

Comment: This isn't enough.  The Dispose method calls Close(), which makes a call across the network to notify the other side to tear down the connection.  If the connection is in Fault, Closing or Closed state then the Close() call will throw an exception and your resource will not be cleaned up.  If that happens, you need to call Abort().  So it is not safe to simply use try/finally or using(){}...

Answer (score 6):

You should not do this.

You should instantiate `MyServiceClient` normally, then `Dispose` of it in the async callback handler.

This is the only way to ensure that the instance will still exist once the callback handler is called, and that it is destroyed after the callback handler has finished its work.